# Certificate problems on Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network deployed with Swarm

Tags: ssl, certificate, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

I've come across this particular problem when deploying a very simple blockchain network on Docker Swarm using the Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.4. It has 2 organizations (2 peers each), 5 orderers (Raft consensus), 2 CA (one for each organization), and 4 couchDB (1 por each peer).

The problem occur when I try to join the peers to the channels that I just created. The message that shows on the terminal:

> Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0org1:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

And when I go through the logs on that peer I see a message that caught my attention:

> createTransport -> DEBU 13c grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {peer1car1:8051 0  }. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate is valid for peer1.org1, peer1, not peer1org1". Reconnecting...

And an actual error message:

> UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 1b9 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=10.0.2.7:50504

Then I started looking on the crypto-config.yaml file and the docker-compose.yaml used to deploy my stack. On the crypto-config.yaml file, I declared de Domain key as "org1" and as you can see on the logs the certificate is valid for peer1org1. But here is the problem, when I declare a service name of "peer0.org1" I get an error from Swarm saying that it's an invalid name.

I know, I know. The message in the log is for another peer but is there a change it is related the this issue I'm having? Any ideas on how to resolve it?

On another subject: I'm new to the container orquestration world and would like to know your opnions. Would you use Kubernetes or Swarm to deploy a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service name as valid in your docker network (I assume it is `peer1org1`) needs to be present in the TLS certificate as subject alternate name (SAN). You can specify SANS in `crypto-config.yaml` as follows:

```
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: org1
    Domain: org1
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Specs:
      - Hostname: peer1
        SANS:
          - "peer1org1"
      - Hostname: peer2
        SANS:
          - "peer2org1"
```

Comment: You solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help. I searched for this SANS key and didn't find anything on the Hyperledger docs. Is it a general key? Do you know why?

Comment: As the cryptogen tool is [not intended for production](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/commands/cryptogen.html#cryptogen), the docs are rather short. Most useful info about the config file is hidden in the default template that you can output using `cryptogen showtemplate`. Or check the [corresponding source code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/common/tools/cryptogen/main.go)